# Rails time table update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

My project has day calender
where period model has
**period_id**(id autoincrement) and **subject**,**teacher_id**,**which_period** ,**day**.

output will be update form  like below

> data in form below as follows (period_id  ,which_period ,day) = hidden
>   ,subject  is input field .

how to achieve this  please help ...

```html
----------------------------------------------------------
|period|        1        |        2        |       3
----------------------------------------------------------
| mon  |  period_id=1    |   period_id=2   | period_id=3
|      | which_period =1 | which_period =2 | which_period =3
|      |      day=mon    |     day=mon     | day=mon
|      |  subject   =1   |   subject  =2   | subject =3 <= input_field
----------------------------------------------------------
| tue  |  period_id=4    |   period_id=5   |  period_id=6
|      |      day=tue    |     day=tue     |    day=tue
|      | which_period =1 | which_period =2 | which_period =3
|      | subject   =4    | subject   =5    | subject   =6
----------------------------------------------------------
                                          | submit|
---------------------------------------------------------
```

view code

```js
    <%= form_for @period, url: welcome_update_path  do |f| %>
      <%= 6.times do %>
           <%= f.hidden :period_id %>
           <%= f.hidden :day %>
           <%= f.hidden :which_period %>
           <%= f.text_field :subject %>
       <%= end %>
      <%= f.submit "Create" %>
    <% end %>
```

controller code

```js
    def update
        @period = Period.find(params[:id]) 
        if @period.update(perio_params)
          flash[:notice]='success'
        end
    end
    private
        def perio_params
            params.require(:period).permit(  :subject  , :day, :which_period)
        end
```

thanks

Comment: If you want people to help, you need to make an effort to ask a question in a way that is easier to understand. If you can't make the effort to use basic grammar such as capitalising the start of a sentence, why do you think people will make the effort to answer? Also it would be better if you posted your data model and relevant code.

Comment: @margo added code with allignments

Comment: @geekghost I dont think that you are clear on what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Your question is VERY unclear, but I think what you are asking is how to implement the saving of multiple calendar records in one process.

The simplest way to do this in Rails is to create a parent object, for example, schedule, which belongs to a user, and has many calendars, and use this "schedule" object as the core of the form.  You can simultaneously create or edit calendar entries that are children of the schedule, and submit them all as request.  Rails can handle them all in one process if you follow the approach taken in the Rails Guides for complex forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms